# Delete the user from the database after a while in Laravel 5.7

Tags: database, laravel, conditional-statements

I had a question, for example, if a user registers on our site but does not verify his e-mail after a while, the user's information will be deleted from our database?
Example:

```
User::all()->where('email_verified_at',null)->delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a timed script in your Laravel App.

First, create a new artisan command

```sh
php artisan make:command ClearUnverifiedUsers --command=my-command:clear-unverified-users
```

In your `app/Console/Commands/ClearUnverifiedUsers.php`

```php
use App\User;
...
public function handle(){
    User::where('is_verified','=',false)->delete();
    $this->info('Clear unverified users!');
}
...
```

add this to your `Kernel.php`

```php
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule){
    // do this command every hour
    $schedule->command('my-command:clear-unverified-users')->hourly();
}
```

last, make sure you had set a timed task in your server:

run this in your server

```sh
export EDITOR=vi && crontab -e
```

add this to `Cron Task Plan`

```
* * * * * php /your-project-location/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

clear your cache

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the user data will not be deleted from the database.

However, the verification link will expire after a while and the user will need to login again to for a fresh verification link be sent.